# CakePHP pagination - order by virtual field

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

Contributors have songs and songs have contributors. I want to be able to sort by the number of songs that a contributor has.

In my Controller:

```
public $paginate = array(
    'fields' => array(
        'Contributor.id',
        'Contributor.name',
        'COUNT(DISTINCT ContributorsSong.song_id) AS Contributor__TotalSongs',
    ),

    'joins' => array(
        array(
            'alias' => 'ContributorsSong',
            'table' => 'contributors_songs',
            'type' => 'LEFT',
            'conditions' => 'ContributorsSong.contributor_id = Contributor.id'
        ),
        array(
            'alias' => 'Song',
            'table' => 'songs',
            'type' => 'LEFT',
            'conditions' => 'ContributorsSong.song_id = Song.id'
        )
    ),

    'group'  => array('ContributorsSong.contributor_id')

);
```

And in my index method.

```
    $this->Contributor->recursive = 0;
    $this->Paginator->settings = $this->paginate;
    $this->Contributor->virtualFields['TotalSongs'] = 0;

    $items = $this->paginate();

    echo '<pre>';print_r($items);echo '</pre>';
```

I'm trying to sort by the number of songs by using a virtual field, so when I go to

localhost/site/contributors/index/sort:TotalSongs/

I get this error:

> Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'order clause'
>
> SQL Query: 
>   SELECT `Contributor`.`id`, 
>   `Contributor`.`name`,
>   COUNT(DISTINCT ContributorsSong.song_id) AS **Contributor__TotalSongs**
>   FROM `db_songs2`.`contributors` AS `Contributor` LEFT JOIN
>   `db_songs2`.`contributors_songs` AS `ContributorsSong` ON
>   (`ContributorsSong`.`contributor_id` = `Contributor`.`id`) LEFT JOIN
>   `db_songs2`.`songs` AS `Song` ON (`ContributorsSong`.`song_id` =
>   `Song`.`id`) WHERE 1 = 1 GROUP BY `ContributorsSong`.`contributor_id`
>   **ORDER BY (0) desc** LIMIT 18

I thought that TotalSongs would get turned into Contributor__TotalSongs in the query but it gets turned into **0**. What is going on here? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I replaced:

```
$this->Contributor->virtualFields['TotalSongs'] = 0;
```

with:

```
$this->Contributor->virtualFields['TotalSongs'] = 'COUNT(DISTINCT ContributorsSong.song_id)';
```

And deleted:
    'COUNT(DISTINCT ContributorsSong.song_id) AS Contributor__TotalSongs',

And it works for ordering now, but I can't use it in the `conditions`. I think this is part of the [Limitations of virtualFields](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html#limitations-of-virtualfields)? I'm trying to select only tables where TotalSongs > 0, but I think I can get this another way, by changing the join from LEFT to INNER.